# Close last 4 characters in breaket of php string

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I have some strings like below

```
my-name-is-2547
this-is-stack-2012
hllo-how-2011
```

Now I want the above strings to be changed to something like the ones below using regex.

```
my-name-is-(2547)
this-is-stack-(2012)
hllo-how-(2011)
```

I don't want to use substr or other, only regex replace.

Comment: For this, regexes are a huge overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pattern = '/(\d+)$/';
$replacement = '($1)';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that a numbers are only at the end:

regular expression:

```
(\d+)
```

using 1 capturing group. Replaced by: ($1).

so the outpu will be:

```
my-name-is-(2547)
this-is-stack-(2012)
hllo-how-(2011)
```